# What is causing this Crashlytics compile warning? (Auto-Linking supplied '...' framework linker option at '...' is not a dylib)

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Compiling my main target (not a test target like [here](https://github.com/bpoplauschi/CrashlyticsFramework/issues/18)) yields this error:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied 
   '~/Documents/my_app/MyApp/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics', 
framework linker option at 
    ~/Documents/my_app/MyApp/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics 
is not a dylib
```

From this build command:

> Ld /Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
>       cd ~/Documents/my_app/MyApp
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dbmrsjmskpqxmnegayfzfxgcwvsm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dbmrsjmskpqxmnegayfzfxgcwvsm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F~/Documents/my_app/MyApp -filelist ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dbmrsjmskpqxmnegayfzfxgcwvsm/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-CocoaLumberjack -lPods-Mantle -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -framework MapKit -framework Fabric -lPods-MyApp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dbmrsjmskpqxmnegayfzfxgcwvsm/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp_dependency_info.dat -o ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dbmrsjmskpqxmnegayfzfxgcwvsm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**The Missing Link:**

This error is almost always produced by not having the binary linked to the library (In this case it would be the `Crashlytics.framework`):

[image: Link Fail]

Trying to build the target `MyApp` (which includes headers with `#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>` will produce the error:

> ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied
>   '../../Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics', framework linker option at
>   ../../Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics is not a dylib

**Link the Framework:**

[image: Link Success]
Fortunately, it should be easy to fix the problem simply by dragging the `Crashlytics.framework` from the `Frameworks` folder in the project navigator into the list of `Link Binary With Libraries` or by using the `+`.

- Make sure you have your App selected/highlighted under Targets while doing this process.

[image]

Comment: Nowadays, the Fabric.framework also needs to be linked in the same fashion.

Comment: Hey, there, I had the exact same issue just recently. I had it with my GGLSignIn from Google and and it was my unit tests that were giving me troubles. So, yeah, the solution was the same but target was MyAppTests, so have that in mind!!

Comment: Yep, this was my solution. (Fabric was linked by another upstream framework of mine, and was included in the final binary, but the compiler insisted on auto-linking it, and telling me about it.)

Comment: This fixed it for me, though in my case the error message was very misleading: the library named in the warning was not the one I had to add! I also was getting undefined symbol errors and the library that defined those symbols was the correct one.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue but my reason was different.

#### Error Output

> ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '~/GameFolder/Pods/Fabric/tvOS/Fabric.framework/Fabric', framework linker option at ~/GameFolder/Pods/Fabric/tvOS/Fabric.framework/Fabric is not a dylib
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Answers", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Answers in GameScene.o
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Answers in AppDelegate.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Crashlytics in AppDelegate.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Fabric", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Fabric in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

#### Reason

- My target was overriding the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`.

#### Solution

- Changed the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` to just inherit the Linker Flags. Basically, changed it to `$(inherited)`

Comment: Yeah, this sorted out my problem. Thanks Indeed. 
PS: I was using cocoapods.

Comment: Glad this was helpful.

Comment: +1. I've been having Cocoapods issues for months. Even went as far as completely wiping and restoring my Mac thinking I had messed some other configuration up. This fixed all my issues and I can use cocoapods effectively again! Thank you!

Comment: this was my problem after switching from Carthage to Cocoapods

Answer (score 6):

I followed all steps provided by @i'L'i but I was not able to find `Crashlytics.framework` and `Fabric.framework` file in build phases.

So this helped me.

**Step 1:** Follow all the steps given [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29656626/3411787)

**Step 2:** Now when you are unable to find `Crashlytics.framework` and `Fabric.framework` files in `Link Binary With Libraries` by clicking `+` do following.

**2.1:** Click on `+` button in `Link Binary With Libraries`.
**2.2:** Click on `Add Other...` button.
**2.3:** Now chose `Crashlytic.framework` and `Fabric.framework` from `Pod` folder - if using cocoapods, else choose both file from where you have downloaded it.

**Step 3:** Build Succeeded, Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, this can also happen if you link your test files to your app target.

For example: 
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1661

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Maybe I messed up the initial fabric install but once I added Fabric.framework to the list of frameworks (should be in the root folder of your app by default) everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Conversely to what I'L'I and user3517250 mention, the problem might also be that you have `#import` statements that shouldn't be there.

Xcode does infer the frameworks to link against from the `#import` statements. If you import a framework that you don't link against, then you get this warning.