# Xcode Build project Error after import AssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

After i draged AssetsLibrary.framework into the project i got errors  when i tried to build project.

[image]

Anyideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Edit including link image

[image]

Comment: Check if Accounts.framework is added

Answer (score 1):

At least you need to link with Assets Library Framework & Core Foundation Framework.

Go to `Target > Build Phases > Link binary with libraries`

Add all the missing libraries

iOS 8 heads-up, from [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html):

> IMPORTANT
>
> In iOS 8.0 and later, use the Photos framework instead of the Assets Library framework. The Photos framework provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library.

Comment: i already have Assets Library Framework & Core Foundation Framework and also all lib which firebase need but still got that errors

Comment: Have you tried to clean you project (use Alt + Clean to Clean Build Folder) & rebuild? You also have some warnings before the errors. Also, review [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29656626/225503) & double check you have all your frameworks linked in the right target. Post a screen capture of your link section, please