# Working with Google Maps SDK CocoaPod install and iOS widgets

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, widget, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im installing the latest `Google Maps SDK v1.10` using `CocoaPods` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)

The install works ok however `Xcode` is unable to compile the widget and gives the following error:

```
(null): Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/tom/Dev/iOS/Noms/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps', framework linker option at /Users/tom/Dev/iOS/Noms/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps is not a dylib
```

Adding the framework manually (which Google doesn't suggest) results in

(null): "_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8", referenced from:

Has anyone successfully installed `GoogleMaps SDK` for an Xcode project with a Widget?

Thanks

Comment: You need to add `CoreLocation` framework to your project. You can add it via `Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`.

Comment: Thanks. That resolved the CoreLocation error however now I see:

(null): Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/tom/Dev/iOS/Noms/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps', framework linker option at /Users/tom/Dev/iOS/Noms/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps is not a dylib. Updated the main question

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152442/what-is-causing-this-crashlytics-compile-warning-auto-linking-supplied-f) about `Auto-Linking supplied` error.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work under The Cocapods installation. I already saw this answer previously and confirmed it doesn't work. There is no Frameworks for the widget, it's copied over from the main app as part of the build phase

Comment: have you resolved it, I am facing the same issue

Comment: No I've not. Until CocoaPods supports widgets I think we need to manually update build settings

Comment: I am seeing this same warning,  but only on my test target.  I am also not quite sure I know what you mean by a widget.  Your last comment seems to imply you got rid of the message by manually updating a build setting, can you tell us which setting?  BTW, as far as I can tell everything run fine on my app.  I did not see this issue until making some change to my pods and moving to xcode 7.1 The changes I made we to remove some pods I had been adding to both targets, now I only have the pods in the main target not the test target

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Worked fine for me
Go to Target -> Build Setting -> Linking -> other linker Flag and add $(inherited) in both Debug and Release[image]

Comment: You made my day man :) all who is facing issue in google map SDK should follow above instruction.

Comment: Could you please explain why this helps :) ?