# Warnings for GoogleMaps Framework in test target

Tags: xcode, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios

After upgrading to Xcode 7.1 and fixing some issues with my cocoapods (I had pods in both the main target and the test target),  I now have the following warnings.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/john/development/OurLatitude/OurLatitude/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks”'
>
> ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied
>   '/Users/john/development/OurLatitude/OurLatitude/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps',
>   framework linker option at
>   /Users/john/development/OurLatitude/OurLatitude/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps
>   is not a dylib

Originally I did only had the `Auto-Linking`

warning, but some how managed to pick up the `directory not found` warning

I have the following in my test target search path:

```
"$(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleMaps/Frameworks" $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks”
```

[image]

If I delete this entry I get the following error:

> ld: framework not found GoogleMaps for architecture i386

at one point I think this was complaining about armv7,  I forget what I changed that affected that.

Including the path in my test target searchpath, is just a warning and everything , including the test seem to run, but I would like to get rid of the warning if possible.

Any ideas?

I tried what was suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152442/what-is-causing-this-crashlytics-compile-warning-auto-linking-supplied-f), but it only seemed to make matters worse.